# How to get only Digits from rows in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

```
MariaDB [cms]> select userLabel from cnf_network_function where nfType='du' order by id desc limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
userLabel: mvnr-cv11|me-mtcil1|123005011
```

===

userLabel: mvnr-cv11|me-mtcil1|123005011

I need only number from above column is it possible?

like

```
select userLabel from cnf_network_function  ........;
```

output should be

```
select userLabel from cnf_network_function  ........;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
userLabel:123005011
```

expectation was --

```
select userLabel from cnf_network_function  ........;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
userLabel:123005011
```

Comment: While this can be solve with [string functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-functions/), you should be putting one piece of data in a column. SQL by the first letter of its acronym is Structured.

Comment: @danblack, Can u provide the steps how to do that?